# Should a minyan that never recites Tachanun at Mincha say Tzidkatcha Tzedek?

Tags: shabbat, chasidut-hasidism, tachanun

[This site](http://dinonline.org/2015/11/13/justification-for-no-tachnun-at-mincha/) states:

> The minhag of many Chassidish kehilos is not to say tachanun at
>   mincha. This minhag is recorded in many Chassidic and Sefardic
>   sources. A number of explanations are offered:
>
> 1  they often daven until after shkiya, and according to many opinions
>   tachanun may not be said after shkiya, so a blanket rule was
>   instituted so as never to come to saying after shkiya, which in some
>   kabbalistic sources danger is associated with this practice.
>
> 2  tachanun by mincha requires intense concentration, which most
>   people don’t have in the middle of their day
>
> 3  after it is night in Israel tachanun should not be said even in
>   other parts of the world

In numerous siddurim that I have seen, there is an instruction next to *Tzidkatcha Tzedek* (said after the Chazan's Amidah repetition of Shabbat mincha) that says that *Tzidkatcha Tzedek* is omitted on occasions when *tachanun* would be omitted. I understand this means Erev Yom Tov, Hol Hamo'ed, Rosh Hodesh, etc. But, would this include those places that never recite Tachanun at mincha, as well?

In viewing the above reasons, I can see not saying it if either it is after *Sheki'ah* in your local area on Shabbat, or if you wish to follow rule #3. (According to rule #3, it seems that in North America, you'd never be able to say it as even at the earliest time allowable for mincha, it's already night in Israel.) But rule #2 seems vague. I don't know what the "intense concentration" aspect is, here. Do they mean specifically business concerns or is it something else?

If places do / should say it, please explain why this is not a "contradiction".

Comment: Looking at the three reasons given in the linked source, I don't think that any of them would apply to *tzidkatcha* on *shabbat*, so I imagine that they would say it.

Comment: Here's an [Arizal siddur](https://books.google.it/books?id=WoUtAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT307) that says it

Comment: @Kazibácsi I had a feeling that Chassidm do it. That seems to indicate that there are different rules here and they don't contradict. Why not?

Comment: If the reasons could be important to the question, as you indicate at the end of your penultimate paragraph, why not include them in the post?

Comment: @Kazibácsi that same siddur on page סח by the weekday mincha says to say tachanun just like shacharis. Therefore it's hard to bring a proof from there

Comment: @aBochur I was just looking for the minchah, but couldn't find it. Thanks for pointing it out!