# Why does Nusach Sefard omit Tachanun during Mincha?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, tachanun, nusach-sefard

In many, if not all, of the Nusach Sefard synagogues I've prayed at, the synagogue does not say Tachanun during Mincha during regular weekdays.

What is the source for this practice?

Comment: It's suggested that very often, it was after sunset.

Comment: @Shalom any source for that?

Comment: A fair number of them skip many Shacharits too for various late / nontraditional reasons

Comment: Answer at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92493/should-a-minyan-that-never-recites-tachanun-at-mincha-say-tzidkatcha-tzedek

Comment: I own a nusach sefard siddir which has tachanun during mincha. If this was specific to nusach sephard then there would be no reason to print it in the siddur. Seems like this would be more narrowly applied then nusach Sephard

Comment: @Dude For this purpose it is probably slightly more accurate to talk about it in terms of "the largely _chasid_-centric practitioners of '_nusach S'farad_'", rather than the _nusach_ itself. If there were a reason among those _chasidim_ to skip it - even every time - that wouldn't necessarily warrant dropping it from the printed _sidur_.

Comment: My point being that the litvish world which has adopted sephard and other chasidim who don't simply skip tachanun for seemingly no reason use nusach sephard and this question wouldn't apply to them

Answer (score 4):

See [here](http://dinonline.org/2015/11/18/skipping-tachanun/) where they suggest:

> 1 they often daven until after shkiya, and according to many opinions
>   tachanun may not be said after shkiya, so a blanket rule was
>   instituted so as never to come to saying after shkiya, which in some
>   kabbalistic sources danger is associated with this practice.
>
> 2 tachanun by mincha requires intense concentration, which most people
>   don’t have in the middle of their day
>
> 3 after it is night in Israel tachanun should not be said even in
>   other parts of the world
>
> Sources: Sefer Nimukei Orach Chaim, Shu”T Dvar Yehoshua Y:D 3:74,
>   Zivchei Zedek siman 9 [minhag bagdad], Sefer Shulchan Hatohar Siman
>   22.

Comment: "3 after it is night in Israel tachanun should not be said even in other parts of the world" - so an 8AM shacharis in California in the winter shouldn't say tachanun either?

Comment: @Heshy and a Chatzot Slichot in Baghdad or Pumbedita would have to wait an hour to start. We all know none of these reasons are the ancient traditions of our ancestors. Picking them apart is mildly fun but practically pretty irrelevant: the people who buy into them don't care.